# Choose personal domain name extension

Tags: dns

I want a domain-name with the extension .vzw (instead of .com for example). I looked at different hosting businesses, but I don't find someone who offer this extension possibility. Does someone know where I can find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. That's not a top-level domain that exists, or that has been applied for. If or when ICANN opens up for a new set of TLD applications, you (or someone else) can try to get it, but until that day you're out of luck.